# Django Rest Framework RetreiveAPIView get() returned 2 results

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django project with a django rest framework. I am trying to use the Retreive API View to return the members details. I want to grab all the member records based on a parameter that is passed in teh url with the groups name. I tried using the `.get()` and `.filter()`. The `.get()` returned an `error of returning more than 2 items`. The `.filter()` is not part of the dict.

I tried `.list` and `.retrieve`

How can I retreive the data objects based with more than 1 item. Here is my View that I am calling.

```
class MemberDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(group__name=self.kwargs.filter('name'))
```

model

```
class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name + ' - ' + self.user.username
```

urls

```
path('members/', MemberListView.as_view()),
path('members/<name>', MemberDetailView.as_view()),
```

_________________________________________-

UPDATE:

so i am getting the error when i override the list:

`TypeError at /api/groups/members/homiez
list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

when  i dont override the list I get an empty results object.

Here is the code I have right now...

```
class MemberGroupListView(ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Member.objects.filter(group__name=self.request.query_params.get('name'))

    def list(self, request):
        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = MemberSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer)
```

models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=42)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=220)
    user_count = models.IntegerField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=12)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='group_images/')
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' - ' + self.created_by.username

class Member(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    host = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group.name + ' - ' + self.user.username
```

urls:

```
path('members/<name>', MemberGroupListView.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RetrieveAPIView is designed for retrieving single instance. You should use [ListAPIView](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#listapiview) instead. And use `get_queryset` method instead of `get_object`

ListAPIView calls serializer with `many=True` param, which returns a list of objects instead of one.

Comment: So I changed it to a list view api. I noticed that it is not filtering by the group name that is passed as a parameter. here is what I have right now...  `class MemberGroupListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(group__name=self.kwargs.filter('name'))` i tried both .filter() and .get()

Comment: `self.queryset.filter(group__name=self.kwargs.get('name'))` should work. kwargs is a dict, so it has no filter method.

Answer (score 2):

Django ORM `get` is used to retrieve only one object. `filter` maybe used to query for multiple objects in a queryset. Hence for retrieving multiple stuff you have to use filter.

In your `View` I think you need to override the `list` method.

```py
class MemberDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        This view should return a list of all the purchases for
        the user as determined by the username portion of the URL.
        """
        username = self.kwargs['username']
        return Purchase.objects.filter(group__name=self.request.query_params.get('name'))

    def list(self, request):
        # Note the use of `get_queryset()` instead of `self.queryset`
        queryset = self.get_queryset()
        serializer = UserSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Note: `self.request.query_params.get()` is how you retrieve data from `request` object. It is about a dictionary operations rather than ORM operations. So don't do `.filter()` on `self.kwargs`.

Comment: I am going to add the code I have not after making the changes. I am getting an error `TypeError at /api/groups/members/homiez
list() got an unexpected keyword argument 'name'`

Comment: Check for `request.GET`what you get? If you get a dictionary you can do `request.GET.dict().get('name')`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Alex's answer, you need to implement the filter method or typicallu add the filter backend to be able to filter querysets based on url filter parameters.
I would go with a filter backend using [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/guide/rest_framework.htm) as it is quite effective, flexiblle and has become quite a standard for Django applications.

You need something like this:

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as filters

class MemberDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_fields = ('user', 'host', 'group')
```

You can read the Django-filter docs for more details on how to use it.